# Add a layout between Recycler View rows?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

What I want to achieve is if I could detect a string within a recycler view item I would inflate something after it and before the next recycler view item is shown.

Comment: Please explain more and show the code what you have tried

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions, that's how you will get answer to your question.

Comment: You can put all your layout in your row and if you detect the string hide the corresponding layout

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll try to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like you have CustomObject class. Take boolean (isCustomView) to add custom layout.

```
public class YourObject {
String customString ="";
boolean isCustomView=false;

public String getCustomString() {
    return customString;
}

public void setCustomString(String customString) {
    this.customString = customString;
}

public boolean isCustomView() {
    return isCustomView;
}

public void setCustomView(boolean customView) {
    isCustomView = customView;
}
```

}

Before sending data to Adapter make this changes to your data

```
 ArrayList<YourObject> yourObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Assume You have yourObjectArrayList with data filled

    // Take temp object 
    YourObject object = new YourObject();
    object.setCustomView(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < yourObjectArrayList.size(); i++) {
        if(yourObjectArrayList.get(i).getCustomString().equals("YOUR CUSTOM STRING")){

            // Adding a custom object before That Position
            if (i==0)
                yourObjectArrayList.add(0,object);
            else
                yourObjectArrayList.add(i-1,object);

            // Adding a custom object After That Position. Note here i+2 is a must
            yourObjectArrayList.add(i+2,object);
        }
    }
    // Add data to RecyclerView adapter & notify
```

Override getItemViewType() in recycler adapter

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (yourObjectArrayList.get(position).isCustomView()) ? R.layout.your_custom_layout : R.layout.your_raw_layout;
}
```

Make below changes to override method onCreateViewHolder

```
 @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView;


    if(viewType == R.layout.your_custom_layout){
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, parent, false);
    }
    else {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_raw_layout, parent, false);
    }

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);

}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort, definitely gonna try this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `int getItemViewType(int);` override method of the `RecyclerView.Adapter<>` class.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    if (data.get(position).contains("Your string"))
        return 007; // any random integer you can use
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

And in the onCreateViewHolder method

```
@Override
public void onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    if (viewType == 007){ // the view type you returned
        return #special_view // inflate your other layout here which you want to inflate if it contains your special string.
    else 
        return #normal_view;// inflate the normal view here and return
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: should I put some loop that would have this?

        myAdapter.getItemViewType(1); or it would be automatically added? I can't make it work

Comment: No dont need to add a loop. In your Adapter class, just override this method and it will be called for the same number of times as you return from `getItemCount() -> Int` @nico dioso

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.dynamicLinearLayout.removeAllViews()
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_layout,null);
holder.dynamicLinearLayout.addView(view);
```

Try this on onBind

Comment: Hello there, this answer doesn't provide solution to the given question as it is unclear what this code is all about, where to put this code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer